# SQL records with multiple values for a field

Tags: sql, database-design, schema

What is the best way to design your table schemas for records that may have multiple values for a certain field?

For example, a document can have multiple concepts associated with it. Each document can have different numbers of concepts as well. I'm trying to design a table where each record is a document along with its metadata, but I'm having trouble with the concepts field. Should I stuff all the concepts into one field called 'Concepts'? Or create different fields for Concept 1, Concept 2, etc. The problem with that is I don't know how many concepts each document can have. I am trying to design this with SQL relational databases, although I know there are object-oriented databases that probably suit my problem better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I stuff all the concepts into one field called 'Concepts'?

No. This would violate the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF#Atomicity) and therefore the 1NF, and cause problems in enforcing integrity and querying.

> Or create different fields for Concept 1, Concept 2, etc.

*Only* if you have a well-defined limit on number of concepts per document, that you know won't change in the future. But you said you *"don't know how many concepts each document can have"*.

> What is the best way to design your table schemas for records that may have multiple values for a certain field?

Depends on whether the same concept can be shared between different documents.

- If **no**, then this is a one-to-many relationship, that can be represented similar to this:

  [image]
- If **yes**, then this is a many-to-many relationship, that requires an extra "junction" (aka. "link") table in between, similar to this:

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is a 'concept' here. Does it mean anything? Is there anything associated with it?
If the value of a fields is meaningful by itself, I'd stick with one field and value of 'enumeration' for it.
In case if there can be additional attributes specific for each 'concept', you'd better consider having a table with 'concepts' and a many-to-many relationship between those two.
I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If the concepts are important, then you should have a `concepts` table.  This would be a reference table that would have a `conceptId` and information about what the concept is.

Then, you can have a table called `DocumentConcepts`.  This would have fields such as:

- DocumentConceptId (a unique id for this table)
- DecumentId
- ConceptId

It might have other information as well, such as a priority (which is first?  which is second?), when the concept was added to the document, and other such information.

Comment: Thanks! Btw I actually have your book, thought I recognized your name from somewhere....